# php foreach/for acting weirdly

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

Someone can solve this mystery? i have two code samples. I think that the second example does same thing as first example but apparently it doesnt.

this works:

```
 print_r($this->facebook->my_retrieve_timeline()['data'][0]->message);
print_r($this->facebook->my_retrieve_timeline()['data'][2]->message);
```

this doesnt:

```
for ($i=0; $i <11; $i++) { 
        echo $this->facebook->my_retrieve_timeline()['data'][$i]->message;
    }
```

error:

```
Message:  Undefined property: stdClass::$message
```

array looks like this:

```
Array
(
[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (

                [message] => bbbbbbbbb

            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (


                [lol] => aaaaaaaaa
            )
        [2] => stdClass Object
            (

                [message] => ccc

            )


    )
)
```

EDIT, SOLVED: so the only problem was that i didnt have message property inside of every object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is because you are trying to access the object property `message` when it doesn't exist.  Also, not an error in this case, but you are also assuming that array indexes 0-10 exist, which might not be the case.

Loop through only valid/existing array elements and check if the `message` property exists before accessing it:

```
foreach($this->facebook->my_retrieve_timeline()['data'] as $data) {
    if(property_exists($data, 'message')) { // or use isset($data->message)
        echo $data->message;
    }
}
```

This doesn't make assumptions about which numeric keys exist (loops only existing elements) and also checks if `message` property exists before accessing it.  As a bonus, it only calls `my_retrieve_timeline()` once instead of every loop iteration.

Comment: OK good but doesn't explain the problem. It's just a free prize.

Comment: Sure it does.  "_Check if the messages property exists first_" before accessing it.

Comment: ooooh me stupid :D , not every of the element had message property, only some had it, so thats why error was

Comment: @AbraCadaver: No, that explains the _solution_, not the _problem_.

Comment: I think the answer is quite clear with _problem_: `message` property does not exist and _solution_: check for `message` property before trying to access it.  Array index description is valid and was answered before OP edited with a `print_r` of array.

Comment: I don't know how to make it any clearer for you. Your answer doesn't explain why the OP's code is broken: it only provides a new piece of code and explains what _that_ does.

Comment: Edited with 2 sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Why did you think they'd be the same? The first example accesses array elements `0` and `1`; the second accesses `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9` and `10`. Clearly at least one of those elements does not exist, given the error message you receive.

There is also a difference between `print_r` and `echo`.

Comment: its not about it, i tried even foreach and same error was, i tried even for with only $i<3 and there are around 23 indexes so fault is somewhere else i guess

Comment: @user3263155: The output you just edited into your question directly contradicts that statement. You have only two elements.

Comment: @BrettSantore: It would also do that if he has notices and error output turn on, yes. (Most people don't.)

Comment: no i have more , i just gave structure, i have +20 elements

Comment: Undefined property != undefined index

Comment: @AbraCadaver: If the index is undefined then it is created for you (but a notice emitted). That automatically created element is not an object with the property `message`.

Comment: `echo $array[1]` does not create `$array[1]` if it doesn't exists.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: It most certainly does: [`$array[1]` there will evaluate to `NULL`](http://ideone.com/Ce6NsO) (and spot the notice I told you that you'd get). Of course, that doesn't mean the `NULL` will be inserted into the array, but that's entirely moot here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  Yes before you edited it ;)

Comment: @AbraCadaver: I just added the last sentence to clarify it for you. But at no stage had I ever claimed that the array would be modified. I provided a link to a live demonstration of what I was talking about, as well as the second explanation of what's going on here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: And the previous one _"If the index is undefined then it is created for you (but a notice emitted). That automatically created element is not an object with the property message."_

Comment: @AbraCadaver: Yes, and it _is_ created, as I just demonstrated and explained several times. I didn't say it was created in the array, did I? It is created as the result of evaluating the expression. This isn't hard.